# C# WPF DataGrid.ItemsSource generates new Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I use a DataTable as source for my DataGrid:

```
  dt.Columns.Add("Update?", typeof(Boolean));
  dt.Columns.Add("Emulator", typeof(String));
  dt.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(String));

  ...      

  dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

The XAML code to the DataGrid:

```
     <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="133" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,81,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="688"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserResize="False" Header="Update?" />
            <DataGridTextColumn CanUserResize="False" Header="Emulator" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn CanUserResize="False" Header="Path" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So if the DataTable is empty I got an empty DataGrid showing the three headers names.
If the DataTable contains items the DataGrid gets extra columns instead of filling the already existing ones.

[image]

What can I do that the DataGrid fills up its existing columns?

Comment: Try to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`

if you set this property as `true` the columns will be created automatically

And also you need to set the binding , sample code :

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Online Order?" IsThreeState="True" Binding="{Binding OnlineOrderFlag}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but this leads to three rows which are empty.

Comment: @GernotLepej you need to set the Binding like `Binding="{Binding Update?}"`